# Which Macs support Airplay mirroring on Mountain Lion?

Tags: airplay, macos

Some people are reporting that Airplay mirroring doesn't work on their Mac running Mountain Lion. Which Macs support AirPlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- iMac (Mid 2011 or newer)
- Mac mini (Mid 2011 or newer)
- MacBook Air (Mid 2011 or newer)
- MacBook Pro (Early 2011 or newer)

Regular Airplay is still supported on all Macs running Mountain Lion.

Comment: I think another easy way to tell is if it supports Airplay mirroring is if it has a FaceTime HD camera since it relies on the same encoder as Airplay.

Comment: What does "Regular Airplay" mean?

Comment: @Pradeep it means Airplay without mirroring, which is only music and movies.

Answer (score 1):

I Read an article today on cultofmac.com that start like this:

> Unless you have a Mac from 2011 or later, don’t expect to be able to do this in Mountain Lion.

The reason, that people are according on, it's about DRM, because only Macs from 2011 and later have intel chips that are able to stream DRM content.

> My best guess is that these Macs ship with Intel chips containing the latest and greatest version of Intel Insider, which allows streamed DRM encrypted Hollywood content to play — just guessing…

*Read more at http://www.cultofmac.com/177259/why-cant-macs-older-than-2011-use-airplay-mirroring-in-mountain-lion/#hWRXMGvrQSLovjVj.99*

Comment: This is a disappointment.  I didn't realize it'd only work on certain Macs :(  My late 2008 MBP is obviously exempt and I have no plans of upgrading anytime soon.

Comment: Meet my friend: **Airfoil.app**: http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/, it works great for me.